# preventing table from growing from long td

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, html-table

I have a table that contains a subtable. I don't want the subtable to influence the width of the table - in the case of overflow, I want the two to scroll independently. Additionally, since the subtable is shown based on a toggle, I don't want the main table rows to jump based on whether or not the subtable is visible

[Here's](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RpKjVO) the codepen.

I think I can accomplish this with `table-layout: fixed`, but I don't necessarily know the contents of the td's, which can be long. If I were to use `table-layout: fixed`, can the td's still grow shrink based on content?

[This](https://react-table.js.org/?selectedKind=2.%20Demos&selectedStory=Sub%20Components&full=0&down=1&left=1&panelRight=0&downPanel=kadirahq%2Fstorybook-addon-actions%2Factions-panel) is an example of what I'd like to do, the nested table scrolls independently of its container table.

Comment: Not entirely sure what you are looking to do with the double scroll but are you [looking for something like this](https://jsfiddle.net/n0ry2651/)?

Comment: Not exactly. I want the table to size itself, without the subtable interfering. For example, when you show the subtable, the original table's td's resize.

Comment: The subtable is nested within the main table and it is show/hide...but you don't want the nested table to influence the main table's dimensions or even resizing main table's td...ok then main table tds will be partially obscured by nested table?

Comment: Sorry, I was following you up until the last sentence? What do you mean by partially obscured? In the codepen, when the nested table is hidden, the main table fits 100%. When it is expanded, the main table grows to the size of the subtable. 

What I want is the main table to remain 100% regardless of whether or not the nested table is shown, and the nested table scroll horizontally when shown.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, what I ended up doing was wrapping the subtable in another table with fixed-layout, in a single td with overflow on. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work in firefox.

```
<td colspan="6">
  <table class="sub-table-container" style="table-layout: fixed; width: 100%">
    <tr><td style="overflow-x: scroll">
       <table class="sub-table">
             ...
```

See [this codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bqgMLY) for the updated solution